# В поисках чего-нибудь или чего-то?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли сказать: "Я в поисках **чего-нибудь** эдакого"?

Или корректно: "Я в поисках **чего-то** эдакого"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слова почти одинаковы. Есть небольшая разница в стилистике:
*что-нибудь* — что угодно;
*что-то* — какая-то неизвестная вещь.

Первый вариант звучит лучше — плавнее, и его удобнее произнести. Второй вариант не очень подходит для книги/статьи, он более разговорный.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Варианты равноправны. Есть небольшая разница в оттенках значения: "что-нибудь" звучит более неопределенно и менее уверенно, как если бы вы были в поисках *хоть чего-нибудь* эдакого, не так важно чего.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.